# Create Node tree from list of paths

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, json

I have this list of paths:

```
private static final List<String> paths = Arrays.asList(
        "assets/css/custom.css",
        "assets/css/default.css",
        "assets/js/main.js",
        "assets/js/old/main-old.js",
        "fonts/poppins.woff",
        "favicon.ico",
        "index.html"
);
```

That I need to create a searchable tree, like this:

[image]

and here's what I have now:

```
public void testCreateTree() {
    Node root = new Node("ROOT", null, Node.NODE_TYPE.ROOT);
    paths.forEach(path -> {
        final Node[] currentNode = {root};
        if(!path.contains("/")) { // root files
            currentNode[0].addChild(new Node(path, currentNode[0], Node.NODE_TYPE.FILE));
        } else {
            String folders = DirectoryRegex.matchFolders(path); // e.g. matches/returns "root/"
            String fileName = DirectoryRegex.matchFile(path); // e.g. matches/returns index.html
            String[] folderArrays = folders.split("/");
            Arrays.asList(folderArrays).forEach(folder -> {
                Node node = new Node("ROOT", null, Node.NODE_TYPE.ROOT);
                node.setNodeName(folder);
                node.setNodeType(Node.NODE_TYPE.FOLDER);
                node.setParent(currentNode[0]);
                // check if child exists
                Node existingNode = currentNode[0].getChild(folder, Node.NODE_TYPE.FOLDER);
                if(existingNode == null) {
                    existingNode = node;
                    currentNode[0].addChild(node);
                }
                currentNode[0] = existingNode;
            });
            currentNode[0].addChild(new Node(fileName, currentNode[0], Node.NODE_TYPE.FILE));
        }

    });
    String print = root.printNodeJSON().toString();
    Console.log(print);
}
```

The **Node.java** class is this:

```
public class Node {
    public NODE_TYPE getNodeType() {
        return nodeType;
    }

    public void setNodeType(NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        this.nodeType = nodeType;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Node parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        if(children == null) {
            children = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Node> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        getChildren().add(child);
    }

    public Node getChild(String nodeName, NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        final Node[] child = {null};
        getChildren().forEach(node -> {
            if(node.getNodeName().equals(nodeName) && node.getNodeType().equals(nodeType)) {
                child[0] = node;
            }
        });
        return child[0];
    }

    public String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
    }

    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    private Node() {}

    public Node(String nodeName, Node parent, NODE_TYPE nodeType) {
        setNodeName(nodeName);
        setNodeType(nodeType);
        setParent(parent);
    }

    public enum NODE_TYPE { FILE, FOLDER, ROOT }
    private NODE_TYPE nodeType;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;
    private String nodeName;

    public String printNode() {
        final String[] s = {"["};

        s[0] = s[0] + "Node name: " + nodeName + ",";
        if(nodeType != null) {
            s[0] = s[0] + "Node type: " + nodeType.toString()  + ",";
        }
        if(getParent() != null) {
            s[0] = s[0] + "Node Parent: [ name = " + getParent().getNodeName() + ", type = " + getParent().getNodeType() + " ]";
        }
        s[0] = s[0] + "Node children: [";
        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
            s[0] = "[" + s[0] + child.printNode() + "]";
        });
        s[0] = s[0] + "]";

        s[0] = s[0] + "]";
        return s[0];
    }

    public JSONObject printNodeJSON() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("nodeName", nodeName);
        jsonObject.put("nodeType", nodeType != null ? nodeType.toString() : null);
        jsonObject.put("parent", getParent() != null ? getParent().printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() : null);
        JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
            children.put(child.printNodeJSON());
        });
        jsonObject.put("children", children);
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public JSONObject printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("nodeName", nodeName);
        jsonObject.put("nodeType", nodeType != null ? nodeType.toString() : null);
        jsonObject.put("parent", getParent() != null ? getParent().printNodeJSONWithoutChildren() : null);
//        JSONArray children = new JSONArray();
//        getChildren().forEach(child -> {
//            children.put(child.printNodeJSON());
//        });
//        jsonObject.put("children", children);
        return jsonObject;
    }

}
```

**The code works fine but I want to know the most efficient way to do this.**

Comment: Would you allow paths like "./" or "temp/../other"?

Comment: Is _DirectoryRegex_ a custom class you have written?

Comment: @dfhwze yes it is a custom class; and no, there will be no empty path, as every absolute path in the List ends with a file (similar to object storages like S3, where the path is actually virtual)

Answer (score 2):

Short take …
`most efficient way to do this`
resources including developer time

… of uncommented code:

Starting with `testCreateTree()` raises hope for a stab at *test first* - I don't see it.

What *is* `this` above: is there more to *tree* than `Node`, how does *searchable* manifest?

- there is no `interface` for `Node`
  (and `testCreateTree()` shows one is urgently needed)
  (what use is *parent* of a `Node`?)
  (come to think of it:
   what use are all the setters?
  `getNodeType()` could use `null == children`, and parent `null` or not)
- one ticklish part in designing `Node` is deciding whether construction of a `Node` with `null != parent` should add the new  `Node` to `parent`'s children.
  (One alternative being an instance method `Node addChild(name …)` which instantiates a child, adds it to children and returns it.)
- the one thing `Node` provides beyond *data members&infrastructure* is *get child by name and type*, which is only useful if there are to be children of identical name, differing in type, only
- with neither assignment nor setter invocation, the lazy instantiation of `children` doesn't work
- `getChild(name, type)` uses linear search (which may be justified if the expected number of children is quite small) - open coded, if using `Iterable.forEach()` (which seems to preclude "early out" - ?):
  if only `java.util.Collection` (or, at least, `Set`) provided for an `E find(Object toEqual)`: implement `equals()` and use that.

  - the use of an array with one solitary element is uncalled for
- "The Way" to support a representation of an instance for human reception is a implementing `toString()`
    - the use of an array with one solitary element is uncalled for

  - use a `StringBuilder` to build strings
  - you don't need to use `.toString()` "in a `String` context" (e.g., `+` multiple `String`s). Doing so allows `NullPointerException`s (which are sidestepped (implicitly) using `String.valueOf()`).
  - there's a way to avoid `<some (involved) lvalue expression> = <same (involved) lvalue expression> <operator> <expression>`: *compound assignment operators* (e.g., `<(involved) lvalue expression> /= <expression>`)
    (should prevent the funny pile of `'['`s at the beginning of the string produced by `printNode()` - that string is formatted horribly, anyway)
- for all I don't know about JSON, I'd pattern support after `toString()` or (de/)serialisation.
- `printNodeJSON()` is weird for duplicating `printNodeJSONWithoutChildren()`'s code instead of using it.
  Neither prints.
- in `testCreateTree()`, you walk the `Node` structure, potentially searching for the same names time and again.
    - the use of an array with one solitary element is uncalled for

  - Why provide parameters to `Node`'s constructor to go on and set deviating values?

  As an alternative, separate *path lookup* and *tree*:
  get the index of the last path part separator (`'/'`), if any.
  if separator was found, use root as folder
  else look up the folder for the part up to that separator (path)
    if not found, create folder(s recursively) linked up with its parent and enter into path->folder lookup
  create a leaf for the part to the end "in" that folder

Comment: (The current fad in getting JSON objects seems to be `Json.createXyzBuilder().add(…).…().build()`.)